# Generating swagger for Dictionary<SomeEnum, string>

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger to generate a swagger document and then using NSwag to generate a C# SDK.

I have a couple classes where I use a Dictionary<SomeEnum, string> to hold miscellaneous properties.

```
namespace Sample
{
    /// <summary>Possible properties for MyClass1 objects</summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum PropEnum1
    {
        /// <summary>OpenAPI doesn't see this description</summary>
        PropName1,
        PropName2,
        PropName3,
        // and more property names
    }

    /// <summary>The first class...</summary>
    public class MyClass1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Properties that vary from instance to instance.</summary>
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public IDictionary<PropEnum1, string> Props { get; set; }
    }

    // There is also a PropEnum2 and MyClass2, but let's stay simple
}
```

Using Swashbuckle 6.14 I end up getting swagger that looks like this:

```
"MyClass1": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "nullable": true
    },
    "props": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "PropName1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "PropName2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "PropName3": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "description": "Properties that vary from instance to instance.",
      "nullable": true
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "description": "The first class..."
}
```

and then NSwag generates a C# interface that looks like this:

```
/// <summary>The first class...</summary>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.4.3.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)")]
public partial class MyClass1
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("name", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Properties that vary from instance to instance.</summary>
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("props", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Props Props { get; set; }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.4.3.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)")]
public partial class Props
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("PropName1", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string PropName1 { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("PropName2", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string PropName2 { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("PropName3", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string PropName3 { get; set; }
}
```

I find the generation of the Props class with a member for every possible enum value a little surprising, but I could live with it.

The problem is that instances of MyClass1 may not have all the properties. I have an API that returns an instance of MyClass1. It works from the swagger page, but using the NSwag SDK gives me an error "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Required property 'PropName2' expects a non-null value."

The immediate issue is the DisallowNull's in the generated Props class. If I hand-edit them from DisallowNull to Default, the SDK works as expected. But hand-editing generated code is not good.

The DisallowNull's come from the PropName properties in the swagger not having "nullable" set to true. If I pause my generation process and hand-edit them into the swagger, I get Required.Default in the generated C# code. But hand-editing generated swagger is also not good.

So one way to fix it would be to get a "nullable" into the properties in the swagger, but I don't know how to do that.

Or is there a way to get Swashbuckle to treat the Props dictionary more like a Dictionary<string, string>?

From [this post](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/844) it seems like a Dictionary<int, string> gets treated this way, but that may be old.

Comment: I've found that hand editing generated code from swagger is sometimes a necessary evil when working with certain C# structures that can't be accurately or easily represented in yaml/json. Imo. You may want to change the structure of the returned dictionary, however, I would just manually change it.

Comment: @DekuDesu Even though I don't work for Google, I try not to be evil. :)
Specifically, I don't want other people to have to remember about the hand-edit.
I do have options, though.
I could write a script to do the edit.
I could change the original source to use Dictionary<string, string>, though that would lose some type-safety. (For the sake of swagger, I have changed [Flag] enums to arrays of plain enums in my APIs.)
I think I'll investigate a Swashbuckle filter to change the swagger generation.

Comment: Are you targeting Swagger JSON 2.0 or 3.0?(default is 3.0)

Comment: 3.0 (doing a SerializeAsV3() to generate the swagger file for NSwag).

Comment: I'm getting somewhere - the DictionaryTKeyEnumTValueSchemaFilter example on the [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) page does the exact opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with. It turns the type into a generic object (where the properties have to be of the valueType. Note that I already have enums serialize as strings, so this may not be appropriate for other people.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// For properties that are Dictionary[SomeEnum, valueType] alter the schema
    /// so the generated SDK code will be IDictionary[string, valueType].
    /// </summary>
    public class EnumDictionaryToStringDictionarySchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Apply the schema changes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="schema">The schema model</param>
        /// <param name="context">The schema filter context</param>
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            // Only for fields that are Dictionary<Enum, TValue>
            //
            if (!context.Type.IsGenericType)
                return;

            if (!context.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<,>))
                && !context.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDictionary<,>)))
                return;

            var keyType = context.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            if (!keyType.IsEnum)
                return;

            var valueType = context.Type.GetGenericArguments()[1];
            var valueTypeSchema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(valueType, context.SchemaRepository);

            schema.Type = "object";
            schema.Properties.Clear();
            schema.AdditionalPropertiesAllowed = true;
            schema.AdditionalProperties = valueTypeSchema;
        }
    }
```